# A word that describes non physical “activity”

Tags: word-choice

With online communication being predominant today what is the collective word that describes accusations, generalizations, insults in people’s comments?  It is not a behavior or conduct since no actual physical activity take place. I want to say for example, “people who engage in such ?????...are...”  “Mental activity” is the only thing that I came up with.

Comment: Why does you  definition of behaviour not include online activity? After all "online behaviour" is a common enough ideom?

Comment: Look in a thesaurus for behavior or conduct.

Comment: The way I understand behavior, one has to physically do something, yell, break, jump etc.  Accusations, generalizations and insults are abstract concepts.

Comment: People who engage in  “ insulting, accusing, generalizing” are ...whatever.  I want to replace “insulting, accusing, generalizing” with a collective word(s)

Comment: *Behaviour* and *conduct* are both applicable to online activities.

Comment: You're overlooking the fact that insults etc. need to be communicated through physical activity - spoken, typed, whatever. And the general word for what you're describing could be *slander*.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say for example, “people who engage in such **trolling**...are...”

OED:

> Draft additions March 2006
>
> **Troll** (v.)  intransitive. Computing slang. To post a deliberately erroneous or antagonistic message on a newsgroup or similar forum with the intention of eliciting a hostile or corrective response. Also transitive: to elicit such a response from (a person); to post messages of this type to (a newsgroup, etc.).
>
> 1992   Re: Post the FAQ in alt.folklore.urban (Usenet newsgroup) 8 Oct.   Maybe after I post it, we could go trolling some more and see what happens.
>
> 2005   B. McWilliams Spam Kings iii. 69   Once, after a spammer trolled Nanae, accusing antis of having no life, Mad Pierre sarcastically responded that the spammer was correct.

Probably from the angling/fishing term "to troll"

> V. Senses relating to angling.
>
> 13. Angling. intransitive. To angle with a running line (? originally with the line running on a ‘troll’ or winch); (also transitive) to fish (water) in this way;
>
> [See also] v. 10a, 10b;  (c) (in U.S. and Scottish use, perhaps through association with trail or trawl) to trail a baited line behind a boat; also figurative.In quot. 1606   perhaps confused with trawl n and v.
>
> 1606   S. Gardiner Bk. Angling 28   Consider how God by his Preachers trowleth for thee.
>
> 1891   A. Lang Angling Sketches 5   Trolling a minnow from a boat in Loch Leven—probably the lowest possible form of angling.
>
> 1966   ‘E. Lindall’ Time too Soon iv. 51   Kamindo had rebuffed him when he had trolled for information.